# Insert in DB a JSON object from a URL

Tags: c#, sql, json, rest, asp.net-core

I'm new to the REST API world. I explain my need: at a specific URL I have a raw JSON text, I would like this text to be acquired by my application and inserted later in the DB as a model I created previously through EF. C# NET-CORE 2.2.

if I wasn't clear enough, don't hesitate to ask me for more details.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I'm sorry if it' was unclear, I will provide more detail:
Actually, i have a JSON string downloaded from an url. I did it with the following code:

```
    var client = new WebClient();
    var jsonFull = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://url"));
```

It's working fine. Now, I need to take from this string only a little part of the JSON, so i did:

```
     using var jsonDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonFull);
     var jsonParsed = jsonDoc.RootElement;
     var myCV = jsonParsed.GetProperty("cv");
```

CVE is an object of this JSON, and I succesfully take it.
Inside this object, there is another one called CV_data, so I extract this:

```
     var myCVLE = myCV.GetProperty("CV_data_meta");
```

The result is a var with inside

```
     ValueKind = Object : "{
      "ID": "CV-2019",
      "ASS": "cv@ms.org"
     }"
```

Now, I have a class like that

```
     public class CV_data_meta
     {
     [JsonPropertyName ("ID")]
     public string ID { get; set; }
     [JsonPropertyName("ASS")]
     public string ASS { get; set; }
     }
```

The question is: how i can put the value in the var myCVLE in the class CV_data_meta?
I tried with

```
     var myCVClass = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CV_data_meta>(myCVLE);
```

But I get an error.
Note: I can't deserialize all the string JSON into an object, because there are a lot of information that I don't need.

Thanks in advance all!

Comment: What did you try? What is your problem exactly? Can you provide a minimal example of what you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from your question, it follows:

You first need to create the JSON object mapping (class) that the API URL will return.

Then consume the API url like this:

```
var client = new WebClient();
   var reply =
      client.DownloadString(
         string.Format("https://www.yourapi.com/yourpath?yourkey={0}", yourkey));
```

receive and map object with mapped class

```
var yourvar = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<yourclass>(reply);
```

Now you have the API return mapped to a class in your application, you can do whatever you want with it, including saving to a database.